# Why are these two code samples equal? Difference between references, borrowed variables, pointers

Tags: pointers, rust, reference, dereference

```
fn largest(num_list: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut largest = num_list[0];

    for &num in num_list {
        if num > largest {
            largest = num
        }
    }

    largest
}

fn largest2(num_list: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut largest = num_list[0];

    for num in num_list {
        if num > &largest {
            largest = *num
        }
    }

    largest
}

fn main() {
    let num_list = vec![30, 20, 10, 60, 50, 40];

    let largest = largest(&num_list);
    let largest2 = largest2(&num_list);

    println!("The largest number in num_list fn is: {}.", largest);
    println!("The largest number in num_list fn is: {}.", largest2);
}
```

As you can see there are some slight differences in ***largest*** and ***largest2***. Can someone help me understand the differences here and why both samples of code actually function the same?

Comment: In release mode on x86_64 the assembly created for both functions is completely indistinguishable. Rust does not do pointer comparisons unless you explicitly use raw pointers so you don't need to be worried about comparing references. The compiler can also recognizes that it only needs to dereference the pointers once so there isn't really an issue there either. Are there any other reasons why you thought they might function differently?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the two samples stems from your loop statement, `for num in num_list` vs `for &num in num_list`. First of all, it is important to understand that they are equivalent to `for [...] in num_list.iter()`, that is, they iterate over references of elements of `num_list`. These references, of type `&i32`, are then assigned to either `num` or `&num`. In the first case, we just have a direct assignment, therefore `num: &i32`. In the second case, there is an [irrefutable assignment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-02-refutability.html) that binds `num` to the number, therefore `num: i32`. Incidentally, this is possible because, even though you are trying to move out a value from a borrow, `i32: Copy`, so Rust compiles it fine.

The rest is just adaptation: either you are using a `&i32`, or directly a `i32`. For instance, when `num: &i32`, and you want to compare it with `largest`, you should dereference `num` and then compare it, giving `*num > largest`. However, `num > &largest` works too because Rust knows how to compare two `&i32`, by dereferencing both (so it will actually produce `*num > largest`). Similarly, when you assign to `largest`, you must assign an `i32`, so you dereference `num`: `largest = *num`.

It's easy to understand, then, why these two pieces of code do the same thing: in one version, you copy the value of a pointer to an integer in `num`, and then use it, whereas in the other you keep the dereference in `num`, and simply dereference it each time you need to use it.